# Maximum Concurrent Queries vs. Maximum Concurrency Slots

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

Below is a screen shot of various Azure SDW performance tiers, concurrent queries and concurrency slots.

[image]

Let's look at the DW500 tier. It offers 32 concurrent queries but only 20 concurrency slots. Since each query consumes at least one concurrency slot (I think), how could this tier actually achieve 32 concurrent queries? It seems to me it would max out at 20. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Some queries in Azure SQL Data Warehouse do not use the concurrency *slots* but will contribute to the concurrent query count, as listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management#operations-not-governed-by-resource-classes).

A note on concurrency slots from the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/resource-classes-for-workload-management#concurrency-slots):

> Only resource governed queries consume concurrency slots. System
>   queries and some trivial queries don't consume any slots. The exact
>   number of concurrency slots consumed is determined by the query's
>   resource class.